# datagridview и tabcontrol winforms c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Есть таблица Rooms и tabcontrol. В таблице Rooms есть Id и Name=Кабинка 1, Кабинка 2 и.т.д. Можно ли взять данные из таблицы Rooms и добавить в каждый tabPage? Я погуглил и не нашел решение.

Comment: Что значит добавить данные в каждый tabPage? Чтобы там такой же dgv был?

Comment: Наример, tabPage1 будет Кабинка 1, tabPage2 ,будет кабинка 2 и.т.д.

Comment: Да пройдитесь циклом for по коллекции «кабинок» или страниц и добавьте «кабинки»  с соответствующими номерами на соответствующие страницы

Comment: Хочу вот как. Если в тблице 6 кабинок должен быть 6 tabPage, если ни одного кабинок тогда tabPage не должен отображать.

Comment: Ну добавляйте табпейджи циклом по «кабинкам» тогда

Comment: ок, понятно, спасибо, попробую.